# Is "mit eine(r) schöne(n) Seidenbluse" in a genitive case?

Tags: preposition, declension

In the following sentence

> Sie trägt meine grünene, italienischen Schuhe und einen weißen Rock mit eine(r) schöne(n) Seidenbluse

Is "mit eine(r) schöne(n) Seidenbluse" in a genitive case? If so, is there an intuitive explanation?

Comment: The dictionary entry in e. g. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/mit#1) seems quite unambiguous in respect to the case (dative). Why are you considering genitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the preposition [*mit*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mit) always demands the dative case. Therefore, only the following is correct:

> Sie trägt meine grünen italienischen Schuhe und einen weißen Rock *mit einer schönen Seidenbluse*.

Answer (score 1):

Nein, das ist Dativ.

> Sie trägt meine grünen italienischen Schuhe und einen weißen Rock mit einer schönen Seidenbluse.

Womit / mit wem oder was? --> Dativ: mit einer schönen Seidenbluse

Wen oder was trägt sie? -> Akkusativ: meine grünen italientischen Schuhe / einen weißen Rock.